# Condition Statement - Php Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli, conditional-statements

I am with Confuse with Condition ..

```
 global $db;

 $sql = " SELECT * FROM TEST";  

 $dbc = mysqli_query($db,$sql)


 if (!$sql || mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0)  {
      // rollback - Transaction
 }

 or 

 if (!$sql && mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0){
      // rollback - Transaction
 }
```

should i use `(!$sql || mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0)   OR  (!$sql && mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0)`

AS if $sql is true  and `mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0 ( false )` then too condition is False (roll-backed)

AND if $sql is false and `mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 4 ( true )` then too condition is False (roll-backed)

> *and if both are false then too roll-backed ..*

***similarly for :***

```
$resultupdate = " UPDATE TEST SET A="NO" WHERE sid="check" ;

if((!$resultupdate) || (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0)) {
  // rollback - Transaction
}

or 

if((!$resultupdate) && (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0)){
  // rollback - Transaction
}
```

Comment: `!$sql` should be `!$dbc`, no ?

Comment: right he needs !$dbc, $sql is only a string

Comment: @ HAL9000, both are different , as "mysqli_num_rows() function returns the number of rows in a result set."

Comment: `if (!$sql)` will never fail, since $sql is a non-empty/non-zero string.

Answer (score 1):

Only one condition can work as you want.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0)  {
 // rollback - Transaction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$dbc || mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0)  {
  // rollback - Transaction
}
```

That's true you're telling php if the query didn't run or it returned 0 rows roll back. meaning in case 1 of these 2 is true you're rolling back

```
if (!$dbc && mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0){
  // rollback - Transaction
}
```

This, you're telling php that both should be true to roll back. if only one is true what's inside this if won't run. That's not what you want.

```
$resultupdate = " UPDATE TEST SET A='NO' WHERE sid='check" ;
$update_query=mysqli_query($db, $resultupdate);
if((!$update_query) || (mysqli_affected_rows($update_query) == 0)) {
  // rollback - Transaction
}
```

for the update, you're testing if the query didn't run, or didn't affect any rows you roll back.

Comment: and what in this case:
$resultupdate = " UPDATE TEST SET A="NO" WHERE sid="check" ;

if((!$resultupdate) || (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0)) {
  // rollback - Transaction
}

or 

if((!$resultupdate) && (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 0)){
  // rollback - Transaction
}

Comment: what @Prix is saying is right, you don't need to test $dbc you just need to test num_rows and affected_rows. I am just clearing your confusion with the && and ||

Comment: hmm yes for UPDATE ... i am check if query didn't run or didn't get effect due to some reason ..hence it will be rollback