# MySQL InnoDB - Transaction with count operation - can count be guaranteed?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I've been reading up on transactions and table locking for a while and I am still unclear on something and hoping to find clarification here:

So the situation is that I need to insert blocks of entries (say 10 at a time) with each one containing a count of the number of entries before the block was inserted  (so rows 51-60 would contain an entry of 50)

Would wrapping the entire process in a transaction be sufficient to guarantee this count in a high IO database?

e.g.

1. Start transaction
2. select (Count *) on table_a
3. insert block of rows on table_a and include count from select
4. End transaction

In the above situation can I guarantee that no rows are inserted between the count and the last insert? (Mysql/InnoDB).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can do this with try..catch ( transaction ), [mypost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749641/php-mysqli-transactions) , also each query you can check with [condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776040/condition-statement-php-mysqli)

Comment: I had a look through those posts and I'm still not clear. Are you saying that essentially I need to run an additional select to verify the counts after the inserts, throw an error if wrong, catch it and rollback. Do I loop this and try again? - I dont want to end with a failed query. Could you present this as an answer for clarity?

Comment: [Check out this](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=49574&hl=) and its working for me